# Signing Issues for Cydia

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, cydia

I am trying my best to update an app for Cydia that is constantly crashing on startup.  It has a base SDK of 7.0 with a deployment target of 6.0.  I have Xcode set to not require code signing.  I have tried this many different ways, and each way, it crashes on startup when I download from Cydia.

First, I tried not code signing and using ldid on my Mac to psuedo-sign it.  I copied the .app file to my desktop and then did:

```
Open Terminal on the OSX system where the application was built.
Add the SHA1 hashes to the application binary:

# cd ~/Desktop/
# ldid -S HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
```

I tested this out by copying it to my iPhone, and it worked fine.  I then uploaded the .app file to thebigboss repository, and when it went live I downloaded it, but it crashed on startup.

My next attempt was to simply create a certificate in Keychain Access.  I left it as a self-signed root and changed it to code-signing.  I put in a unique serial, and left valid days at 365.  I then tried using it in Xcode but Xcode gave me an error that it was no longer valid and I needed to check the expiration date of my certificate.

I really need help with this, as I cannot figure out for the life of me what is going wrong here, and customers on Cydia are getting upset.

Comment: `ldid` has caused me nothing but grief. I just sign with my developer account: `codesign -fs "Johnny Developer" <program>`.

Comment: If `ldid` works for you to sign it locally, then simply copy to your iPhone, then `ldid` is working fine.  Something else is going on.  Have you checked the ownership and permissions on your files that get stuffed into the debian package? How are you building the .deb file (command line scripts, iOSOpenDev, etc.)?  Have you emailed Optimo or BigBoss about this?  I've had trouble with this before, and sometimes it's an issue that gets resolved on the repository end.  Also, is this a fat or "thin" binary?  Which architecture(s)?